# com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException: (126) ERROR: ERROR Message 172 of class 29 type E

Tags: sapjco3

I am getting below exception while executing the `JCoFunction`.

```
JCoFunction functionBOMCreation = destination.getRepository().getFunction("CSAP_MAT_BOM_CREATE"); functionBOMCreation.execute(destination);
```

Getting this exception

```
com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException: (126) ERROR: ERROR Message 172 of class 29 type E
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcClient.execute(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:1824)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ClientConnection.execute(ClientConnection.java:1120)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.ClientConnection.execute(ClientConnection.java:953)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.RfcDestination.execute(RfcDestination.java:1317)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.RfcDestination.execute(RfcDestination.java:1288)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.AbapFunction.execute(AbapFunction.java:302)**
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you get `AbapException`, it means that the called function has explicitly found an error. It may be an error in the arguments you pass to the function or an error due to data in SAP system.

You may possibly receive a message number with it. If so, you may obtain the text by either logging into SAP system manually (via SAP GUI) and run `SE91` transaction code to display the messages, or your program can do an additional call to the function `BAPI_MESSAGE_GETDETAIL` to get the full message text (input parameters: `ID, NUMBER, MESSAGE_V1, MESSAGE_V2, MESSAGE_V3, MESSAGE_V4`; output parameter: `MESSAGE`).

In your case, the message ID `172` of class `29` corresponds to the text `Enter a quantity`. I don't know `CSAP_MAT_BOM_CREATE` so I can't tell you what exact parameter is concerned.